# Gluing two affine curves to make a smooth curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, curves, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry, projective-varieties

Let  $C_0: y^{2}=x^4-7$ be a genus $1$ curve.

Let another  affine curve be

$C_1: v^{2}=u^{4}(1/u^4-7)=1-7u^4$.

The glueing maps between the two charts are given by

$(x,y)\mapsto (1/x,y/x^{2})$

and

$(v,v)\mapsto (1/u,v/u^{2})$

Gluing these two curves gives gives projective variety $C$.

I have question about this curve.

$1.$ Why is $C$ a curve in $\Bbb{P}^3$, not in $\Bbb{P}^2$?

$2$. Why is $C$ smooth ? (This is a main question)

I'm wondering what the equation of $C$ is, but these question need no equation of $C$, Regarding $1$. Regarding $1$, $C_0$ and $C_1$ are affine charts of $C$, and $C_0$ and $C_1$ is singular in its projective closure, so $C$ seems to be singular also, I'm wondering where singular point was removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you start from a polynomial of degree 4, it seems hard to me to describe the elliptic curve $C$ as a cubic in $\mathbb P^2$. I think it is simpler to give it as complete intersection of 2 quadrics in $\mathbb P^3$ as follows.
First consider the closure of $C_0$ (or $C_1$, it is the same) in the wheighted projective space $W:=\mathbb P (1,1,2)$: $y^2=x^4-7w^4$ ($y$ is the variable of degree 2). Now, you can embedd $W$ in $\mathbb P^3$ (with coordinates $(a,b,c,d)$) via $(x:w:y)\mapsto (x^2:xw:w^2:y)$, whence the equations describing your curve are $$ac=b^2\quad d^2=a^2-7c^2$$
It should be now easy to see that $C$ is smooth.

This curve $C$ is the normalization of the projective closure of $C_0$, and the singular point was removed and replace by $C_1$.

Comment: It seems really magic-like way to me.Thank you very much. But  why you choose $\Bbb{P}(1,1,2)$ not just projective space $\Bbb{P}^2$ to embed $C_0$ into $\Bbb{P}^3$ ?

Comment: As you show, if we could find exact equation in $\Bbb{P}^3$, it is easy to judge smoothness, but I'm stuck with how to do that. You way is really cool, but at the same time, I don't have confident to imitate your clever way.

Comment: $\mathbb P(1,1,n)$ is the natural ambient space of any hyperelliptic curve given by an equation of the form $y^2= f_{2n}(x,w)$, with $f_{2n}$ homogeneous polynomial of degree $2n$.

Comment: Regarding the smoothness, isn't $C$ smooth as it is smooth on each affine chart?

Comment: Yes, they are smooth affine curves. They have singular points in projective closure. So what I want to do is to embed $C_0$ into $\Bbb{P}^n$ for some $n$. Just embed projective closure of $C_0$ in $\Bbb{P}^2$ to $\Bbb{P}^3$ by $(x,ω,y)\mapsto (x^2,xω,ω^2,y)$ isn't enoug?  Then, projective closure in $\Bbb{P}^3$ is $ac=b^2, d^2c=a^2-pc^4$, indeed , this is smooth curve in $\Bbb{P}^3$.

Comment: I still don't understand why you should take weighted projective space.

Comment: Well, your map is not well defined, as the monomials have different degrees. The way to repair it, is precisely using weighted coordinates.

Comment: Why is your map $(x:w:y)\mapsto (x^2:xq:w^2:y)$ embedding ? I think this is not injective because $(x,w,y)$ and $(-x,-w,y)$ goes to $(x^2,xw,w^2,y)$.

Comment: $(-1)\cdot (x,w,y)= ((-1)x,(-1)w, (-1)^2 y)=(-x,-w,y)$, so the 2 points coincides in $\mathbb P(1,1,2)$

Comment: Oh you are correct, thank you very much.